# Algorithm or function for navigating around a clock face or compass (or any other circle)?

Tags: c#, java, algorithm

I'm looking for a nice elegant way of navigating around discrete increments of a circle.

So imagine giving a hand on a clock an instruction to move clockwise or anti-clockwise one increment. Starting at 1 and moving clockwise this is easy - just add one. But when you reach 12 and add one, the algorithm needs to reset back to 1, rather than 13. Similarly, going the otherway - when you move anti-clockwise from 1, the algorithm should move you to 12, rather than zero.

My initial idea is to use modulo, so imagine 12 increments, the function might be:

`new_position = ((curr_position + 12) + increment) % 12`

But this clearly doesn't handle the transition from 12->1 or from 12<-1.

I'm sure there's a nice way to do this...

Answer (score 4):

Part of the problem is that you're thinking 12:00 == 12.  This becomes easier when you realize 12:00 == 0.

Comment: When I was in my early teens I wrote a BBS and I screwed up 12 AM/PM so many different ways I can't even remember them all.

Comment: Of course I realise 12 equals 0. I don't see how that realisation helps particularly.

Comment: Because it allows you to modulus the number by 12 after every incremental move. A move from 11->12 equals (11+1)%12 == 0. From there you continue to add. For subtracting increments, test for a negative and add 12 until it's positive.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want `if` to check for negatives and add 12, you can use the following (I'm not sure it is elegant though):

```
((current+increment) % 12 + 12)) % 12
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not optimal, but I would do :

```
int GetTime(int current, int increment)
{
    int result = current + increment;
    return result >= 0 ? result : result + 12;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This algorithm is O(n), but it should work well for reasonable inputs.

```
private static int AdvanceHours(int hour, int hoursToAdvance)
{
    Debug.Assert(1 <= hour && hour <= 12);
    hour += hoursToAdvance;
    while (hour < 1)
        hour += 12;
    while (hour > 12)
        hour -= 12;
    return hour;
}
```